# opendkim: Restore /etc/default/opendkim to original values

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, opendkim

I accidentally overwrote my /etc/default/opendkim while changing the configuration. How can I restore it to the "factory defaults"?

I already tried uninstalling and re-installing the package.

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt.8.html

Answer (score 2):

you should purge the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge packagename
```

it will remove all configuration files and then you can install it fresh